# Jsoup website login throwing unknown exception

Tags: java, jsoup

> I attempt to login to my school's grade book website to display the HTML with the following code:

```
public class Connect {



public static void main(String[] args) {

    String pageURL = "https://parents.mtsd.k12.nj.us/genesis/parents?tab1=studentdata&action=form";
    String param1 = "&tab2=gradebook";
    String param2 = "&tab3=weeklysummary";
    String param3 = "&studentid=";
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    String initURL = "https://parents.mtsd.k12.nj.us/genesis/parents?gohome=true";




    //System.out.print("Enter Student ID: ");
    //String sID = input.nextLine();
    String sID = "not shown";

    String URLF = pageURL + param1 + param2 + param3 + sID;

    connectTo(URLF);


    // write your code here
}

public static Document connectTo (String URLF){

    String loginURL = "https://parents.mtsd.k12.nj.us/genesis/parents/j_security_check";
    String userDataUrl = URLF;
    String username = "not shown";
    String password = "not shown";

    Connection.Response res = null;
    Document doc = null;

    try {

        res = Jsoup.connect(userDataUrl)
                .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.4 Safari/537.36")
                .header("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8")
                .timeout(500)
                .method(Connection.Method.GET)
                .execute();

    } catch (IOException io) {

        io.printStackTrace();

    }

    try {

        doc = Jsoup.connect(loginURL)
                .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.4 Safari/537.36")
                .referrer("https://parents.mtsd.k12.nj.us/genesis/parents?gohome=true")
                .cookies(res.cookies())
                .data("j_username", username)
                .data("j_password", password)
                .post();


    } catch (IOException ioe) {

        ioe.printStackTrace();

    }

    if (doc != null){
        System.out.print(doc.text());
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

> However, when I run this, I get the following error:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:  sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:  sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1949)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:302)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:296)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1506)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:979)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:914)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1062)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
at  sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDele gateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:153)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:512)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:493)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:205)
at com.gs.Connect.connectTo(Connect.java:58)
at com.gs.Connect.main(Connect.java:35)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:146)
at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:131)
at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:382)
... 26 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.gs.Connect.connectTo(Connect.java:71)
at com.gs.Connect.main(Connect.java:35)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

> Now, I am not sure why this is not working as I have been using this similar process (with Jsoup) to login/parse information from similar websites and I haven't run into any issues. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Have a look at this post about your exception [unable to find valid certification path to requested target](http://nodsw.com/blog/leeland/2006/12/06-no-more-unable-find-valid-certification-path-requested-target) and how to solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short explanation for the origin of the execpetion `unable to find valid certification path to requested target`.

Java will establish secure connections over SSL only if it trust the certificate. The certificates which are trust are stored in the truststore ${JAVA_HOME}/lib/security/cacerts. The trustore contains the a list of well known certificate authorities (CA). If the certificate of the remote server is neither signed by one of the CAs in the trustore nor the certificate of the remote server itself is in the trustore the connection will not be trust and the `SunCertPathBuilderException` is thrown.

In this case the certificate is signed by `GoDaddy.com` which is not in the Java trustore. So have to add manually the server certificate either in the default Java trustore or in a separate `your_keystore.jks` one.

The below steps explain how to download the server certificate and store it in a separat keystore. This keystore then will be used for the validation of the server certificate.

**Don't do that by default** for all by Java not trusted connections. Before you do so, **you** must ensure that the server you connect to is the one you want to connect to.

First you need to download the certificate of that webpage.

E.g. using Chrome browser (steps described for Linux, Windows is similar, OSX check the comments below):

- open webpage `https://parents.mtsd.k12.nj.us`
- click on the lock icon in the addressbar (before `https://`)
- in the dialog click on the tab `Connection`
- click on the link `Certificate information`
- in the `Certificate Viewer` click on the tab `details`
- click on the button `Export` and save the certificate in format `BASE 64 encoded single certificate` as file `owa.mtsd.us.b64` (can be any other file name)

[image: steps 1-4]
[image: steps 5-6]

Next create a keystore file (one command line)

```
keytool -import -noprompt -trustcacerts \
    -alias owa.mtsd.us -file owa.mtsd.us.b64 \
    -keystore your_keystore.jks -storepass YourPasswd
```

Following snippet successfully established a connection

```
// without setting your created keystore
// a sun.security.validator.ValidatorException will be thrown
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "your_keystore.jks");
String url = "https://parents.mtsd.k12.nj.us";
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
System.out.println("doc = " + doc.text());
```

output

```
doc = One Moment...
```

Comment: I do not see a button for exporting the certificate

Comment: @Steve Have a look. I added some screenshots.

Comment: @Steve Click on the certificate image and drop it on the desktop. It will be named `owa.mtsd.us.cer`. Amend the `keytool` command as `... -file owa.mtsd.us.cer ...`.